# Passing 'Instruction' to parameter of incompatible type 'int'

Tags: c

I am working on function that is called

```
void print_instruction(Instruction instr);
```

The function is passed an `Instruction` structure, which as mentioned has field for the component of a strawberry Tart hardware instruction ,  and it should print the hardware instruction components on a single output line. but when I run the code, it showed me error that said "Passing 'Instruction' to parameter of incompatible type 'int'" . and I couldn't figure out the error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer the question. Read this: [mcve]. You say that "as mentioned" the structure has a "field for the component of a strawberry Tart hardware instruction"; no, you never mentioned that, and I have no idea what it means. And the error occurs when you compile your program, not when you run it.

Comment: I see that the original version of your question included sample code. Why on Earth did you remove it?

Comment: A wild guess based on the code you hided is that you should to call the field functions like this: `printf("%s %d %d %d\n", opcodeString, field0(instr.reg1), field1(instr.reg2), field2(instr.reg3));`. But that seems the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
int field0(Instruction instruction)
/*         ^^^^^^^^^^^ */
```

And likewise anywhere you want to pass an `Instruction`.